# White-gaps is sound profile recorded with shotgun microphone

Tags: audacity, shotgun, clipping, birds

I got recently interested in bird sound recording. Apologies as this might be a noob question! Attached here the sound profile from Audacity:

[image]

Set-up:

- RØDE NTG5 with Zoom u22 (for converting XLR analog to USB digital)
- Merlin App installed in M1Pro MBP.

My questions are –

1. What are those white gaps marked by the arrows, when a bird is calling?
2. Frequencies above 16,000 Hz seems to be not recorded at all, is the signal getting clipped?
3. Any suggestions to improve these?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you identify the white signal areas as gaps? Also, all digital recorders have a sampling limit, above which no frequencies can be recorded.

Comment: Merlin seems to be a productivity app. It might only be sampling at 32kHz.

Comment: @RoryAlsop, those white spots are having no signal, isn't it? I thought, in this kind of graphs, anywhere completely white means no audio signal...

Comment: @Tetsujin, actually the set-up is 'non-conventional'. The app is designed for iPhone/iPad (probably the best app for identify birds using live sound), not for MacOS - in which I ran it. There's no option to modify (or know) the sampling rate in the app AFAIK. In audio recordings with the iPhone Merlin app shows no such problem.

Comment: @massisenergy - I don't know. Is that correct?

Comment: I know nothing of these bird apps or what the goal is, but it looks like there's a faint harmonic naturally at twice the fundamental, and the white space falls below this second harmonic but seems to cut off below 8 kHz. There's an obvious relation between 8, 16 and 32 kHz, so I have a feeling this is a format conversion issue of some kind. It could be psychoacoustic masking if it's a lossy format. Yeah, I'm not sure, I think more info is needed, TBH.